# react native how to get the value within TEXT tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text

I was trying to get the value of a  tag in react-native

```
<Text>paragraph </Text>
```

on the web we use inner HTML to get the value of a tag.
what to use in react-native to get the value within of Text tag??.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store it in state as you may also want it to update at some later point of time.

```
state={
 textValue:'default text'
}

updateText=(newValue)=>{this.setState({textValue:newValue})}

render(){
 return(
  <Text>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
 )
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since the OP is asking a way to directly access the value,it can be done by using ref.

```
<Text ref={node=>this.textRef=node}>Hello world!</Text>
```

Now you can get value as `this.textRef.props.children`.

Here is an expo link for [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/text-value)

Comment: i dont need to update . i just need to get the paragraph. i tried <Text ref='myText'>This is my text</Text>
<Button onPress={()=>alert(this.refs.myText.props.children)} title='Press Me'/>  but not working giving error like Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i1o1C83rlDdBEiKp9j5-fQCiknw62XOQ                            expo is giving error